# How to connect to server via ssh when a port was accidentally changed to over 65535?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, port, limit

Accidentally I was changed my ssh port to over 65535, but 65535 is limit.
And I can not connect via ssh now.
Server is cloud hosted.
Suppord does not have phisical contact with it.
How I can connect to it? Thanks!!!

Comment: You don't have out-of-band management of any kind?  Who is the cloud hosting provider?

Comment: No, havent. Provider is linode.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do** have out-of-band management if you're using Linode.  Use Lish, login and fix the sshd config.

https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/using-the-linode-shell-lish

Answer (score 2):

The TCP port number is an unsigned two byte integer which explains why it caps out at 65535.  There typically isn't a function in the standard library to parse shorts from text so I quite often use something like strtoul() or atoi() and cast the result.  Its likely that your ssh daemon is doing something similar.  If that is the case, you may be able to calculate the truncated value.  This truncated value would be the value that you entered MOD 65535.  For instance, if you specified 65536, the truncated value will be one.

Comment: hmmm. What is means? MOD 65535? What I must to do? Thanks!

Comment: @Dimitry G MOD is the remainder operator.  Dividing 65536 by 65535 gives an integer value of one and a remainder of one.